# Data size of a calculated column in PowerBI vs. column in a csv

Tags: csv, powerbi

I'm relatively new to PowerBI so please excuse my ignorance. I'm building a report in PowerBI, where I import a csv called "df". Currently, df.csv is too large and I run into a memory error when attempting to refresh. I've tried most of the readily available tools to decrease the data size of df.csv but it is still too large.

I also have some calculated columns, made in PowerBI. My question is, will the memory allocation be less if I created these columns upstream? I could create these columns myself in R, then export to csv.